# With PayPal webhooks, why is WebClient giving me FAILURE while HttpClient is giving me SUCCESS?

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I am working with PayPal webhooks with C# ASP.Net and I am very confused why I keep getting FAILURE when I make the call with WebClient but when I use HttpClient, I am getting SUCCESS.

Here is the WebClient call:

```
  var client = new WebClient();
  client.Headers.Add("authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
  client.Headers.Add("content-type", "application/json");
  client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
  // this returns FAILURE from PayPal
  string response = client.UploadString("https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/notifications/verify-webhook-signature", "POST", paypalVerifyRequestJsonString);
```

Here is the HttpClient call:

```
  HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
  httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);     
  var content = new StringContent(paypalVerifyRequestJsonString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
  var resultResponse = httpClient.PostAsync("https://api.sandbox.paypal.comv1/notifications/verify-webhook-signature", content).Result;
  // this returns SUCCESS from PayPal
  var responseBody = resultResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

paypalVerifyRequestJsonString is the JSON I compose and send back to PayPal according to [the PayPal webhook page](https://developer.paypal.com/api/rest/webhooks/#subscribe-to-events). It's the same for both code segements above. The code to get the accessToken is also the same for both code segments above.

I can't figure out why WebClient keeps failing. I have been using WebClient in my C# ASP.Net Get Access Token, Create Order, and Capture Payment methods and WebClient has been working fine for them. But I can't get WebClient to work for webhooks (ie. return SUCCESS) when I make the call PayPal.

Comment: You are probably failing authentication.  See : https://developer.paypal.com/api/rest/authentication/

Comment: No. If it returns FAILURE, it's not an authentication issue. Also the authentication in both examples is given as the same, and one of them works.

Comment: Why would you want to use `WebClient` anyway, it's ancient? Side note: you are not doing async right. You need to use `await` and `using` like this `using var resultResponse = await httpClient.PostAsync(...); using var responseBody = await resultResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();`

Comment: @Charlieface Yeah, await and async is a whole other topic. I am having trouble debugging in Visual Studio when I use await and async.  Right now, I just want working code with PayPal sandbox.  Once I get it working with PayPal sandbox, I will revisit async and await.

Comment: @jdweng I think the authentication is working, because I can get SUCCESS with the second code snippet using HttpClient. I just can't figure out why WebClient doesn't work.

Comment: The default http headers are different when you use different tools.  So usually in cases like this you just need to modify the headers.  Using a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and comparing working and non working can solve issues like this.